# Why do I get "Missing configuration for public_key" error on Laravel-sentry?

Tags: php, laravel, sentry

We use Laravel 5.6.35 on project. We want to include Laravel-Sentry in this project.
The actions I take in order are as follows;

**Step 1:**

[image: Laravel version and .env configuration]

**Step 2:**

[image: app\Exceptions\Handler.php report function prepared]

**Step 3**

```
$ php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Sentry\SentryLaravel\SentryLaravelServiceProvider"
```

All settings and configurations seem correct, but I get "*Missing configuration for public_key*" error.

```
> php artisan sentry:test
[sentry] ERROR: Missing configuration for server
[sentry] ERROR: Missing configuration for public_key
[sentry] Client configuration:
-> server:
-> project: 1
-> public_key:
[sentry] Generating test event
[sentry] Sending test event with ID: 2fc1b22135c14c338e0006eb67d69cc7
```

I tried all the solutions on the [github issue topic](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-laravel/issues/127) but could not get results.

We use the sentry-laravel version 0.9.2.

```
"sentry/sentry-laravel": "^0.9.2",
```

---

**Question:** Could it be causing this error? What can be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for error.

*config/sentry.php*

```
<?php

return array(
    'dsn' => env('SENTRY_DSN'),

    // capture release as git sha
    // 'release' => trim(exec('git log --pretty="%h" -n1 HEAD')),

    // Capture bindings on SQL queries
    'breadcrumbs.sql_bindings' => true,

    // Capture default user context
    'user_context' => true,
);
```

I change dsn env key as `LARAVEL_SENTRY_DSN` and succesfully run.

**After Change config/sentry.php**

```
<?php

return array(
    'dsn' => env('LARAVEL_SENTRY_DSN'),

    // capture release as git sha
    // 'release' => trim(exec('git log --pretty="%h" -n1 HEAD')),

    // Capture bindings on SQL queries
    'breadcrumbs.sql_bindings' => true,

    // Capture default user context
    'user_context' => true,
);
```